# Mapping the oracle database directory object to a network path

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I'm an accidental DBA. We have oracle database running on windows server.

I created an oracle directory object named 'Result' and mapped it one of the local drives (C:\appResult) on the database server. The front end application creates a report and writes the file to 'Result' and a file thus gets written to C:\appResult. Now, we want to change the file path 'C:\appResult' to some other server in the network (another server in the network). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com is the best spot for dba questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY...` variant of this command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY RESULT AS '\\ServerName\ShareName\SomeOtherDir'
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: If the network path has credentials (windows server) how can we pass the username & password?

Comment: @Konstantinos: that should be asked as a separate question on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).  Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to give ip name with username and password in directory path?

Comment: I have no idea. You should post that as a new question.